# Error in python while creating pie charts and arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pie-chart

I am working on a cancer cell research and I am trying to make a pie chart to display the mitosis X death percentage. Hence I have an array named     mitosis_events and another one named Death_events and below is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mitotic_events[get_generation_number(cell)] += 1
death_events[len(cell)-1] += 1

#Simple Pie chart

# The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
labels = 'Mitosis', 'Deaths'
sizes = [mitotic_events, death_events]
colors = ['Green', 'Red' ]
explode = (0, 0.1) # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')

plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
    autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
# Set aspect ratio to be equal so that pie is drawn as a circle.
plt.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

and I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I wonder what is the solution? I know the problem is in this line:

```
sizes = [mitotic_events, death_events]
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Try to debug your code with print at least. Also, you can google your error and find answer.

Comment: I obviously googled but nothing relates to my request + I know the error is in this line  "" sizes = [mitotic_events, death_events] ""

Comment: Your code snippet is not complete, since you do not show the definitions of `mitotic_events` and `death_events` and `plt` (though the last is obvious). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RoryDaulton I fixed it now

Comment: I just put text of error to google and find similar topic and you could do the same.

Comment: @Budulianin Thank you for your help I have already done that and tried to fix it but it is not working, I always leave stackoverflow as a last resort

Comment: You have improved your code but you still have undefined variables. You do not show the creation of `mitotic_events` or `death_events` or `get_generation_number` or `cell`. You really need to read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure your code is *complete*, which means that when I copy and paste your code into a blank module and try to run it I will get the error message that you are seeing. See my answer for what is probably happening to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not fully show the definitions of `mitotic_events` or `death_events`, since those use `get_generation_number()` and `cell` which are not defined in your code snippet. You also do not show how those first two variables are *created*--you just show how they are *updated*. However, we see from the statements

```
mitotic_events[get_generation_number(cell)] += 1
death_events[len(cell)-1] += 1
```

that both `mitotic_events` and `death_events` are lists. You then define

```
sizes = [mitotic_events, death_events]
```

thus `sizes` is a lists of lists. You then try to pass `sizes` as the first parameter to pyplot's `pie()` function.

However, the first parameter to `pie()` must be an array of numbers or a list of numbers. The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie) implies that but does not say it clearly, but the [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html) and [tutorial](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-pie-chart/) show that must be the case. When pyplot reads `sizes` it looks at the first item in the `sizes` list and sees that it is not a number (scalar) but is a list. Pyplot apparently tries to change that inner list `mitotic_events` to a scalar but it is a list of length greater than one so the conversion fails. Pyplot then gives you that not-very-helpful error message.

The solution is for you to construct `sizes` so it is a list of numbers. Probably you should construct it with

```
sizes = mitotic_events + death_events
```

to properly combine those two lists, but you would probably need to change your other parameters to `pie()`. You do not give enough information for me to say much more.